# Division of the Binomial Coefficient

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-theorem

Prove that when p is prime, the binomial coefficient p!/(r!)((p-r)!) is divisible by p with r being greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to p-1 .

Clearly p! is divisible by p so I cant seem to see the need for any further working.

However the solution states that none of the prime factors of r! or p-r! are divisible by p (I do not disagree with this statement) whilst p! is evidently divisible by p. Hence p!/(r!)((p-r)!) is divisible by p.

Please could someone help explain the necessity of the prime factors explanation in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number $a=\frac{6}{3}$. Suppose someone told you

> The numerator $6$ is divisible by $3$, so no need for further work: $a$ is divisible by $3$.

Where did they go wrong? Do you see why investigating the denominator is relevant?

Comment: So surely in this case, I need to check that p! is not divisible by r! or (p-r)! ? Why do they check that r! and p-r! are not divisible by p? thanks

Comment: $p!$ ***is*** divisible by *both* $r!$ and $(p-r)!$; otherwise, the quotient $\dfrac{p!}{r!\,(p-r)!}$ couldn't possibly be an integer. If a denominator has a factor of $p$ that could **cancel out** the factor of $p$ in the numerator, *then* you'd be in trouble; that's why it's what they check.